# Error while bundle install on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I installed `RVM` on server.

Then put all code of application. Goto application folder and type `bundle install` i got below error.

```
root@xxx:~/myprj# bundle install
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:7:in `<main>'
```

I already installed `bundler` on server.

What is actual problem i can not found

any one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.

I uninstall ruby-2.1.2 from rvm and installed again.

Its solve for me.

Thanks